# 500 Internal Server Error when moving Yii project to cPanel

Tags: .htaccess, yii, cpanel

I have some problem when moving Yii project folder to public_html in cPanel File Manager. In localhost `http://localhost:8888/eKehadiran/index.php` it works fine, but when i'm moving the project to public_html and run `ekehadiran.com/index.php`, the ERROR was appear.

This is some related file on public_html:

.htaccess

```html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

index.php

```html
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What error are you getting in error_logs file ? Please check that and try to disable that .htaccess line.

Comment: this is the kinda of error from log file:
`SoftException in Application.cpp:603: Directory "/home/mrdidie/public_html" is writeable by group`

Comment: yeayyy ! thank you for your suggestion for view the error_logs file. Now it is work. I change all of the PERMISSION that the error give in error_logs

Comment: Yes, If you are using suphp on your server then you need to assign permission 755 and 644 to folders and files respectively

Answer (score 1):

try adding following lines in index.php

```
<?php

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

// change the following paths if necessary

it should show you the error